# Aggregate totals for DATEDIFF() calculations

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to get aggregate sums for days between certain dates. I have managed to use DATEDIFF to find the number of days, but cannot find a way to add them.

Here is what I would like the table to look like. Please note that dates are in UK format and days counted include both Start and End date. I also have removed weekends so that this only includes weekdays:

```
User     |   txtStartDate   |   txtEndDate   |   Days   |   Days Total
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |   04/01/18       |   05/01/18     |    2     |      2
1        |   09/01/18       |   12/01/18     |    4     |      6
1        |   22/01/18       |   31/01/18     |    8     |      14
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2        |   11/01/18       |   12/01/18     |    2     |      2
2        |   18/01/18       |   18/01/18     |    1     |      3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                 TOTAL  |      17
```

I am using this code to calculate the days:

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.day, Fields!txtStartDate.Value, Fields!txtEndDate.Value)+1)
-(DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!txtStartDate.Value, Fields!txtEndDate.Value)*2)
```

and have tried putting this in =SUM() to calculate the total but this does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: How did you use `SUM()` and what clarify what you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: I tried just adding an expression to the Days Total cell:

        =SUM(
     (DateDiff(DateInterval.day, Fields!txtStartDate.Value, Fields!txtEndDate.Value)+1)
     -(DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!txtStartDate.Value, Fields!txtEndDate.Value)*2)
)

This just outputs the same number as it would without SUM(). I have also tried =SUM(ReportItems("Days").Value) but this creates an error  saying that only Report Items in Headers and Footers can be used.

Apologies for the formatting, its not wanting to play properly in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [RunningValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-runningvalue-function?view=sql-server-2017)

You might get a syntax error here

```
=RunningValue(DateDiff(DateInterval.day, Fields!txtStartDate.Value, Fields!txtEndDate.Value)+1)
-(DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!txtStartDate.Value, Fields!txtEndDate.Value)*2)
,sum
,"DataSet1") --enter the scope here or `nothing`
```

Comment: This seems like it might work but I am having trouble finding the correct scope, I keep getting an error as I am not inputting the correct syntax. I assume the scope would be the 'Days' cell?

Comment: I have got it working by using the Dataset as the scope, but this gives a continuous aggregate sum. Is there a way to have it restart the sum for each individual user?

Comment: I think you would need to play around with Column Groups

Comment: Ill have a play and let you know how it goes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Change "Dataset1" in the RunningValue expression to match  your row group name (eg. User). If you don't have a row group you need to create one (there is no need to use the group headers/footers)

Comment: It worked by using the row group as the scope. Just had to play around with the Sorting settings within the group before it looked how I wanted it to. Thanks again for the help!